# Does Deferred Execution works in the same way for method syntax and query syntax in LINQ/Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to know if `Deferred Execution` can be used for queries in **method syntax** and **query syntax** , I'm interested to know if there are any difference. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is only *method syntax*. When you write your query with *query syntax*, compiler translates it to method syntax (actually to static methods calls).

Example:

Extension method call (method syntax)

```
var query = sequence.Select(x => x.Property);
```

Is compiled as (yes extension methods are just a syntax sugar for calls of static class methods)

```
var query = Queryable.Select(sequence, x => x.Property);
```

Same result gives (this is a syntax sugar for same Queryable/Enumerable methods calls)

```
var query = from x in sequence
            select x.Property;
```

So, both syntaxes produce same code. Thus there is no difference which syntax you are using - deferred execution (and anything else) will work in the same way.

Comment: Well, actually I pointed that both syntaxes produce same result (static method calls). If result is same, then deferred execution works in the same way :) But agree, I'll add this remark

Answer (score 3):

Query syntax is just syntactic sugar for method syntax, so there is no difference.

Comment: But does not mention deferred execution which seem to be the core topic.

Comment: The is no difference in _anything_, including deferred execution, because both method and query syntax are the same under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

Deferred execution is same for both. Query syntax actually compiles to method syntax at compile time.

[LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax (C#) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

> Most queries in the introductory LINQ documentation are written as
>   query expressions by using the declarative query syntax introduced in
>   C# 3.0. However, the .NET common language runtime (CLR) has no notion
>   of query syntax in itself. Therefore, **at compile time, query
>   expressions are translated to something that the CLR does understand:
>   method calls**. These methods are called the standard query operators,
>   and they have names such as Where, Select, GroupBy, Join, Max,
>   Average, and so on. You can call them directly by using method syntax
>   instead of query syntax.

Comment: + the only one you has at least mentioned the core topic _"deferred execution"_.